# Making a text dissappear after x second [C]

Tags: c, time

I have some homework about a "hangman" game and initially I need to show the rules on the console for only 5 seconds after which it must dissappear and the game will start. How can I achieve this in C?

For example:

> "You can only try 5 times"

After 5 seconds this should dissappear and the game will start.

I am using the DEV-C console and have researched the time.h library but the part I'm most stuck at is how to make the text dissappear.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: What is your "console"? Something like LCD hardware?

Comment: This will also be related to the OS you are using, so you could add the code that you have and that I suppose is not doing what you want, and explain where is this code supposed to run.

Comment: To be honest it is a project we didn't learn anything about time.h fonctions i have made a search on this site but i couldn't manage to write correctly. However i use Dev C++'s Console. Edit: I'm pretty new in programming.

Comment: @KironIstiniar Can you pay someone to help you with this? I have a friend that could help you.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: @iharob i prefer not to it is not my full project it is only a point that i couldn't manage. I have writen the game's code already but i need that time function and i don't think paying someone to make your homework is something nice or ethic. Edit:Windows 7

Comment: I know, and I am glad that you think that way. But asking help online with no effort shown is almost the same. What does the function `sleep()` tell you just from it's name?

Comment: İ searched but it is my first time that i write a question on this site or any other. Okey, i looked sleep (5); but i need to dissappear my printf("x") function. This is where i exactly stuck with.

Comment: The answer below seems to cover what you need to do, but please edit the question to reflect what you wanted (so that it may help others), and remove the apologies.

Comment: @leeror  "Samidamaru" sent me a suggestion for edit. I changed it thanks to him. Thank you everyone you were really helpfull and i hope this question will help all who stuck in this like me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this using `sleep` if you don't need to do anything during those 5 seconds:

```
int main()
{
    printf("You can only try 5 times");
    sleep(5);

    // Start game

    return 0;
}
```

For dissappearing text you alluded to in comments you can use carriage returns `\r`:

`printf("\rI will overwrite the previous text!");`

But this only works if you're overwriting with a string longer than what's already printed. You can print a blank line first to 'erase' it to get around this.

Finally, as most output streams are buffered, your text may not print without the newline `\n` character straight away, to get around this you can use `fflush(stdout)` so your final implementation might look something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf("\rYou can only try 5 times");
    fflush(stdout);
    sleep(5);

    printf("\r                          ");
    fflush(stdout);
    printf("\rThe game will now begin.");
    fflush(stdout);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that will do !